# Не могу подключить изображения через file-loader в webpack

Tags: webpack

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
 entry: './src/index.js',
 output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
 },
 plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: 'OlympTest',
  favicon: '',
  template: 'src/index.html'
 })],
 devServer: {
  contentBase: './dist'
 },
 module: {
  rules: [
   {
    test: /\.sss$/,
    use: [
     'style-loader',
     'postcss-loader'
    ]
   },
   {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
    use: [
     {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
       name: '[path][name].[ext]'
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
};
```

В html подключаю вот так

Comment: В html подключаю вот так <img src="img/Logo.svg" alt="Logo">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в невнимательности и в htmlWebpackPlugin, все пути до файлов пишутся так "<%- require('./img/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png') %>"